# gulp-rename creating unnecessary directories

Tags: gulp, gulp-rename

I am using gulp to resize and rename some images:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imageResize = require('gulp-image-resize');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

var resizeImages = function resize(options) {
  gulp
    .src('original-images/**')
    .pipe(changed('./'))
    .pipe(imageResize({ width: options.width }))
    .pipe(rename((path) => { path.basename += options.fileSuffix; }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/img/'));
};


gulp.task('resize-images', () => {
  const desktopImageResizeOptions = {
    width: 356,
    fileSuffix: '-desktop',
  };
  const tabletImageResizeOptions = {
    width: 291,
    fileSuffix: '-tablet',
  };
  const phoneImageResizeOptions = {
    width: 721,
    fileSuffix: '-phone',
  };
  resizeImages(desktopImageResizeOptions);
  resizeImages(tabletImageResizeOptions);
  resizeImages(phoneImageResizeOptions);
});
```

This works - it puts the resized renamed images into the correct location, with the suffix added to the file name.

However, it also creates directories called `-desktop`, `-phone` and `-tablet`. How can I prevent this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by specifying file endings, and therefore not passing in the directories. So the src on line 8 became

```
.src('original-images/**/*.{jpg,png}')
```

Comment: had same stupid problem, thanks for posting your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also deal with more complex cases. If the function passed to the `rename` function doesn't change the file's path it will be omitted. In the following example the file will not be renamed if it hasn't an `extname`

```
.pipe(rename(function (path) {
    if (path.extname !== "") {
        path.basename += "-" + options.width;
    }            
}))
```